# Is there an async equivalent of setUpClass in Python 3.10?

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, pytest-asyncio

I have been using `unittest.IsolatedAsyncioTestCase` to test my async methods. I have been making use of `setUpClass`, `asyncSetUp` to create fixture and `asyncTearDown` to cleanup. This is all working merrily so far :-)

But now I have a new requirement which is to asynchronously create some fixtures once per test class and use it by the test methods throughout.

I am aware `setUpClass` is run once per test class and `setUp` is run once per test method.

`asyncSetUp` is async equivalent of `setUp`. But I dont seem to find an async equivalent of `setUpClass`.

So, what is the best way to asynchronously create and cleanup fixtures once per test?

I tried the official unittest doc at https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUpClass, but it only documents about the `asyncSetUp`.

I am on Python 3.10 and using pytest.